# Is it possible for a client to make a request using a dynamic URL and still use a client side cache?

Tags: html, caching

I'm stuck having to work around an existing bad design.

Our client team will (for logging reasons apparently) have to inject a dynamic value somewhere into their request URL even for the same resource. This of course busts all client side caching as the browser sees it as a new resource.

My question: Can anything be done so the browser can recognize these dynamic urls as the same? Some magic header? Tricky use of etag? Anything?

Comment: In a word no. This is how cache busters work so. So you client team have written a nice cache buster for you

Comment: The only thing that comes to mind is a web worker which will actually rewrite the url to a cached one client-side.